# If $A$ is positive semi-definite, how to determine the positive definiteness of $B^TA B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, definition

If $A$ is a positive semi-definite matrix and $B$ has a arbitary rank, how to determine the the positve definiteness of $B^TAB$ ? ($B^T$ is the transpose matrix of $B$)

I found that this product $B^TAB$ can be positive definite or positive semi-definite. So I think the positve definiteness may depend on the rank of $B$, but I cannot give a rigorous derivation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

You know that the matrix $|M$ is positive definite if, for all $x\neq 0$, you have $$x^T Mx > 0$$ and it is positive semidefinite if you replace "$>$" above with "$\geq$".

Now, taking $M=B^TAB$, you can rewrite $x^TMx$ as

$$x^T(B^TAB)x = (x^TB^T) A (Bx) = (Bx)^T A (Bx).$$

Can you continue from here?

Comment: Thank you. But I still cannot solve it. Continuing from your last equation, it depends on the relationship between (left) null space of A and the colunm space of B. How can I proceed from this ?

Comment: @YuHooo You know that $A$ is positive definite. For a general vector $y$, what can you say about the sign of $y^T A y$?

Comment: Thank you. But $A$ is only positive semi-definite in the question, so I think the sign of $y^{T}Ay$ is not clear (I can only tell it is non-negative). Considering this, my conclusion is : if $R(B)\cap N(A) = \{0\}$, i.e. the union of the column space of $B$ and the null space of $A$ only includes zero, then $B^{T}AB$ is posive definite; otherwise,  $B^{T}AB$ is posive semi-definite. Is that right ?

Comment: @YuHooo Not quite. Your condition is correct in that if it is not met, then the matrix is positive semi-definite. But if it is met, then the matrix is positive definite only if $B$ is of full rank and has more rows than columns. If $B$ is not of full rank, or has more columns than rows then there exists an $x$ such that $Bx=0$, and then $x^TB^TABx=0$.

Comment: Thank you, that means it can be divided into two cases according to my condition. Could you help me simplify this conclusion ?

Comment: @YuHooo I think the way I wrote it can't really be simplified any further...

Answer (score -1):

Let $y=Bx$.  Then $x^T B’ A B x = y^T A y \geq 0$ since $A \geq 0$.  Since this is true of all $x$, $B’ A B$ is positive semidefinite.